# How many IDL files are needed when there are multiple components in a distributed system?

Tags: distributed-computing, idl

This is the scenario.

There are three components, A, B and C.

Component A can access methods of component B.
Component B can access methods of component A and component C.
Component C can access methods of component B.

To implement this scenario how many [interface description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) (IDL) files are needed? How many stubs and skeletons do we require?

I was thinking four IDL files. But can we have multiple stubs and skeletons?

Comment: 3 IDL files would be enough and you could restrict through the 3 skeletons that would be generated.

Comment: Can somebody confirm this please?

Comment: One. You could put all three services in one IDL. At least theoretically (I probably would not do that, but that's not what you asked for), and without further specification of the exact instance of the IDL concept you are talking about. There is no such thing as "*the*" IDL.

Comment: How did you get four IDLs from three services? @mayooran's three is sufficient, in fact I have no idea what you think the four one would be.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your services/components (number of methods), I would rather try to split them into logical units rather than based on the number of computers you want to connect.

For example, it can make sense to have two different services implemented by the same server: One for internal purposes and one that is to be published. Or a service is split into two parts, because these two parts do not really belong together logically, although they are for some reason implemented by the same component. All of these services may or may not share the same IDL file.

Last not least, if you still want to minimize the amount of files, keep in mind that declaring, publishing and knowing about a certain service interface does not imply, that a given component must implement the service, must be able to reach the service, wants to use the service, or is allowed to call it.